# Active Record database Organization

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm creating my first web app as an assignment. I am writing my project proposal and part of the proposal is to create a schema.

The app concept is simple, it's creating a workout log, where users can create, edit and delete workouts all kept in an organized log.

I am having trouble thinking about the best way to structure the database so when a user wants to fetch a specific workout, it comes with all exercises and their results.

So far I've come up with this layout. I guess workouts.exercises.results would gather the correct information, but I wanted to know if their was a tidier way to organize this data as it is my first time and I am trying to create this using best practices.

### workouts

**column name**

id
name
user_id
updated_at

### exercises

**column name**

id
name
workout_id
updated_at

### results

**column name**

id
exercise_id
workout_id
sets
reps
duration
updated_at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, `Workouts has many exercises`, `Exercise has one Result`.

If yes, then you don't need workout id in result table.

For fetching the records by `workout`, use the following code:

```
w = Workout.find(workout_id)
w.exercises.each do |e|
   puts "Exercise=#{e.name} and result = #{e.result}}
end
```